# Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED BUG?

Tags: javascript, android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im having this problem or bug I guess, I am trying to figure this problem for days and im out of options.
Im trying to build and debugg my app on real device. I have already tried through extensions, android studio, etc.. but always it ends up on  error Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED.
Im 100% positive that the routes are aiming right to android-js-engine-release.aar (can send more screenshots). I dont really what to do, If it is bug could you please tell me what to use instead of background runner?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE9S3.png)

I have also made reinstall of background plugin, deleting Gradle cache, clean build, recompilling dependencies...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution. I manually removed Android folder and reinstalled it with "ionic cap add android". For first time the error came back but with more info where is the .aar file missing, so I made new "libs" folder and copied it from backgroundrunner.